# multiplication by taking into account the values when creating a matrix on the matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am writing code in Matlab.

A matrix:

```
[2    1     4     3;...
10   15    20    10;...
20   10    15    20];
```

B matrix:

```
[1    3   4;..   
 4    5   6;... 
 2    1   4;...
 3    5   1];
```

C matrix:

```
[50;100;25;10];
```

I need to create a new matrix. I will use the values in matrices `A`, `B` and `C` when creating this matrix. I will try to explain how I want to create my new matrix through an example.

The matrix we want to create will be a 2x4 matrix.

Values in matrix `A` are important. First of all, the values in the first column are checked. The value of `A(1,1)` is 2. So the second row values in `B` and `C` are multiplied. But in `B` there are three columns in the second row. We must choose one of the three columns. When choosing, we consider the values in the second and third rows of `A`. If it is 10, the first column in `B` matrix is multiplied by `B(2,1)`. If it is 15, the second column in `B` matrix is multiplied by `B(2,2)`. if it is 20, the third column in B matrix is multiplied by `B(2,3)`.

New matrix :

```
[400    150    10   75;...
  25     50    50  100];
```

What code is required to create such a matrix?

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to show the composition of each number in your desired output? At the minute it's not clear to me how each value is generated, e.g. `400=B(2,1)*C(2)` - this would rule out any ambiguity in your description

Comment: The question is unclear (or at least, my interpretation does not match the suggested output), but a first pass answer would be something like this:
`for ii = 1:2; for jj = 1:4; D(ii, jj) = B( A(1,jj), A(ii+1,jj)/5-1 ) * C( A(1,jj) ); end; end;`. If the question can be clarified this would ideally be done without loops.